# Adding CSS at runtime to an ASP.net master page.

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have an ASP.net web application, and would like to know if is it possible to change the CSS of a site at run time of a master page, and get the CSS file name from a SQL database and add it into the system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put on the top of the masterpage on aspnet literal and construct the link in the pageload of the masterpage that way you could put a css there

```
<asp:Literal ID="Css" runat="Server" />
```

Then on the page load

```
var cssfilename  = GetCssFromDatabase();
Literal.Text = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all\" " + cssfilename  + "\" />";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Use `<head runat="server">` and you can put anything in there, simplest way probably a `Literal` control where you append the string from codebehind

Masterpage.master:

```html
<head runat="server">
    <title>Your Site</title>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="cssLiteral" />
</head>
```

Masterpage.master.cs:

```
cssLiteral.Text = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='"+strCssFileName+"' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much information of your case, yes it's possible in many ways. Here is a simple example how to change css-file in master-page from a content page:

First add a static variable for example in Global.asax (code in VB.Net)

```
Public Shared DefaultCssFile As String = "~/MyStyles.css"
```

In master pages header:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(MyApp.Global_asax.DefaultCssFile) %>" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Then just change the variables value as you see fit.

```
MyApp.Global_asax.DefaultCssFile = "~/MyOtherStyles.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can achieve this.

Best way I suggest you to use theme and skin file concept.

```
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    switch (Request.QueryString["theme"])
    {
    case "Blue":
        Page.Theme = "BlueTheme";
        break;
    case "Pink":
        Page.Theme = "PinkTheme";
        break;
    }
    }
```

here you can change the values of your theme run-time from code behind accurately. you can put your .css files into different themes. and as per database conditions you can change values of theme files.

hope this will help.